# Im having trouble overriding material-ui root style for DialogActions

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have two buttons in a DialogActions [like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O374U.png)

The JSX I have is the following:

```
<DialogActions classes={{ root: classes.dialogActionsLeft }}>
  <Button
    autoFocus
    onClick={() => {
      setOpen(false);
    }}
  >
    Cancel
  </Button>
  <Button
    onClick={() => {
      setOpen(false);
      navigate("/");
    }}
  >
    Finish
  </Button>
</DialogActions>
```

And the CSS I have is:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dialogActionsLeft: {
    "&:nth-child(1)": {
      justifyContent: `flex-start`
    }
  }
}));
```

If the pseudo selector isn't there both buttons will be left aligned, and if it is there, both buttons stay right aligned. This tells me I'm using the pseudo selector wrong but I can't figure out how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to left align both buttons?
If that is the case, try `&:nth-child(n)`.

Update

You must specify justifyContent for dialogActionsLeft as well.

```
dialogActionsLeft: { justifyContent: 'space-between', '&:nth-child(1)': { justifyContent: flex-start, } }
```

Comment: No I need the first button left aligned and the second button right aligned.

Comment: You must specify justifyContent for dialogActionsLeft as well.

`  dialogActionsLeft: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    '&:nth-child(1)': {
      justifyContent: `flex-start`,
    }
  }`

Comment: Glad to hear that.
I have edited my answer. If you can, accept it as the answer. If not, no worries.